# Image field is not updating while in import

Tags: magento-1.8, import, image

I have CSV file and when i import the file , file imported successfully but image field is not updated.Product added to list but without image.

In the csv i checked and it has image link.How can i solve the issue.

May be some hints works for me.I tried these links examples but not succeeded.[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16628071/magento-image-upload-using-import-export-does-not-work-it-upload-all-the-info)

Answer (score 1):

1. First, make sure the file you are using as image exists in
   `media/import` and is readable.
2. Then make sure the file name in your csv starts with a `/`.
   (`/some_image.jpg`).
3. Check if the `media` folder is writable
4. Check if the column name in your csv file matches the attribute name (`image`, `small_image`),